# Division and Subtraction using DATEDIFF in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Getting Wrong calculation in the Attendance Percentage at  **[AttenPerc]** will be calculated from **([TotallectdHoursForStu] /[TotalAttenHoursForStu]) * 100**.       and Wrong Hours in **[AbsentHours]** I want to subtract **[TotalAttenHoursForStu]    from [TotallectdHoursForStu]** to get exact difference in **hh:mm:ss** ,  and Absent Percentage in  **[AbsPerc]** will be calculated from **([AbsentHours] /[TotalAttenHoursForStu]) * 100**.  Check the Report End of Code you will understand what I mean.  You will notice in the first row the **attendperc** is **-2.310** where it should be **57.142%** and AbsentHours is **22:36:00** which should be **01:22:00**  and AbsPerc  is 102.31 which should be **42.85 %**. Hope you understand my question..

```
USE [dbmairTime]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[StudentReports]    Script Date: 5/7/2015 09:29:47 ص ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[StudentReports]  @StuColNum nvarchar(50)
as
select subjectname,Subjects.totalHours,
CAST(DATEADD(mi,SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime) as float)),'00:00')as time(0))as [TotalAttenHoursForStu],
CAST(DATEADD(mi,SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,LecturerAttendance.AttenedTime,LecturerAttendance.LeaveTime) as float)),'00:00')as time(0)) as [TotallectdHoursForStu],

/**** The Percentage isn't right ***/
CAST(((SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))/SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),LecturerAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))))*100 as float)as [AttenPerc],

/**** Absent Hours isn't right ***/
CAST(DATEADD(mi,(SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(LecturerAttendance.AttenedTime,LecturerAttendance.LeaveTime),LecturerAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))-SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))),'00:00') as time(0)) as [AbsentHours],

/***** Percentage isn't right *****/
100-CAST(((SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))/SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,COALESCE(StudentsAttendance.AttendTime,StudentsAttendance.LeaveTime),LecturerAttendance.LeaveTime) as float))))*100 as float) as [AbsPerc]
from StudentsAttendance inner join Subjects
on Subjects.subjectid=StudentsAttendance.Subject_ID
inner join LecturerAttendance
on LecturerAttendance.SubjectID=StudentsAttendance.Subject_ID and LecturerAttendance.DivisonID=StudentsAttendance.Division_ID
where StudentsAttendance.StudentCollNumber=@StuColNum 
group by Subject_ID,Subjects.totalHours,subjectname
```

Here is Sample of the Reports When I Execute the StudentReport with the Student ID

```
[StudentReports] 431041282

   subjectname  totalHours  TotalAttenHoursForStu   TotallectdHoursForStu   AttenPerc           AbsentHours  AbsPerc
    S111        50          03:16:00                 01:52:00               -2.31023102310231    22:36:00    102.310231023102
    M222        50          00:11:00                 00:11:00                100                 00:00:00        0
```

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. please tag only appropriate RDBMS

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? The report works if you specify a Student ID? Under what circumstances does it error, and what error messages does it give you?

Comment: What errors do you get? I find that the easy way to solve these problems is to comment out everything that works, and break down the problematic parts to the smallest pieces possible.

Comment: I modified the Question and edited the summary. Waiting your answers...